# How to set color for non plotting Area in HighChart

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, charts, highcharts

[image]

I created this graph by using HighChart but it's not displaying gray color with maximum value. I want to set this in my chart so How can I do this?

Currently My graph display like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `plotbands` on xAxis or add additional `columnrange` series. Take a look at examples I prepared for you and in case of any question feel free to ask.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Ccolumnrange%3E
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Ccolumn%3E.grouping

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/5sujjcz0/ - using plot bands
http://jsfiddle.net/wh14dwe9/ - using additional series